# Change the css when tbody doesn't have a row using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the `css` through `jquery` if table body doesn't have a row. How can i achieve this? Here's my approach. My problem is it doesn't work, I tried to put an `alert` inside the `if` statement but `alert` doesn't show up. I want to hide the `table` if `tbody` doesn't have a `tr`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tbody = $(".table-condensed tbody");
  if (tbody.children().length == 0) {
    $(".blankdata").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center blankdata">EMPLOYEE NAME</th>
      <th class="text-center blankdata">DESCRIPTION</th>
      <th class="text-center blankdata"># of Payments</th>
      <th class="text-center blankdata">LOAN AMOUNT</th>
      <th class="text-center blankdata">TOTAL PAYMENT</th>
      <th class="text-center blankdata">BALANCE</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-warehouse">
    <tr id="blank">
      <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
      <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
      <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
      <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
      <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
      <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
      <td class="text-center"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So, what is the result of your approach?

Comment: Yes, what is the question there?

Comment: @Geshode it doesn't work. I tried to put an `alert` inside the `if` statement but `alert` doesn't show up.

Comment: you want to check blank rows right? not if there is a `tr` or not?

Comment: @Ryxle i want to check if there is tr or not

Comment: @nethkennnnn according to your js code you are checking whether the children count is 0 or not. But since you have one row your if condition won't execute. you can test your code by removing tr.

Comment: seems to work for me when i delete the <tr>s from <tbody> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ypvdxR

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError he used `blankdata` for `th` tags also. so those will get hidden.

Comment: @nethkennnnn are you talking about the `tr` element or data inside `tr` element.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right. All you have to do is change the condition to `!==` temporarily to check your **css** property.

Since you have a `tr` inside, the if condition is failing. If you remove your `tr`, your if condition will run fine. In this case you can temporarily change it to `!==` to check that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tbody = $(".table-condensed tbody");
  if (tbody.children().length !== 0) {
    $(".blankdata").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center blankdata">EMPLOYEE NAME</th>
      <th class="text-center blankdata">DESCRIPTION</th>
      <th class="text-center blankdata"># of Payments</th>
      <th class="text-center blankdata">LOAN AMOUNT</th>
      <th class="text-center blankdata">TOTAL PAYMENT</th>
      <th class="text-center blankdata">BALANCE</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-warehouse">
    <tr id="blank">
      <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
      <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
      <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
      <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
      <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
      <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
      <td class="text-center"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
if (!$('.table-condensed tbody tr').length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change if condition to

```
if($('.table-warehouse').html().replace(/ /g,'') == '')
```

[**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wc94ypw4/)

Comment: Doesn't work. Itried to put an alert but it didnt trigger the alert.

Comment: try now.. you need to replace the whitespace character also

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect whether there is no `<tr>` tag under `<tbody>`, you can use `find()` method of Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tbody = $(".table-condensed tbody");
  if (tbody.find("tr").length == 0) {
    $(".blankdata").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

However, in your example there is a `<tr>` element inside `<tbody>`, so the length is not 0.

In addition; If there is no  tag, you can not change its css of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
if($(".table-condensed tr").length==0))
  $(".table-condensed tr").css("display", "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current markup dose not produce `true` condition because you have `tr` inside `tbody` that means `if (tbody.children().length == 0)` is `false`. I have checked it is really empty `tbody` it is working fine for me:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center blankdata">EMPLOYEE NAME</th>
      <th class="text-center blankdata">DESCRIPTION</th>
      <th class="text-center blankdata"># of Payments</th>
      <th class="text-center blankdata">LOAN AMOUNT</th>
      <th class="text-center blankdata">TOTAL PAYMENT</th>
      <th class="text-center blankdata">BALANCE</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-warehouse">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your HTML please find working code bellow

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    td, th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th class="text-center blankdata">EMPLOYEE NAME</th>
                 <th class="text-center blankdata">DESCRIPTION</th>
                 <th class="text-center blankdata"># of Payments</th>
                 <th class="text-center blankdata">LOAN AMOUNT</th>
                 <th class="text-center blankdata">TOTAL PAYMENT</th>
                 <th class="text-center blankdata">BALANCE</th>
                 <th></th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody class="table-warehouse">
              <tr id="blank">
                 <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
                 <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
                 <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
                 <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
                 <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
                 <td class="text-center blankdata"></td>
                 <td class="text-center"></td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var applyclass = true;
        var tbody = $(".table-condensed tbody");
        tbody.find('td').each(function() {
            var st = $(this).html();
            if($.trim(st) != ''){
                applyclass = false;
            }
       }) ; 
        if(applyclass){
           $(".blankdata").css("display", "none");
        }
    });  
    </script>
    </html>
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in footer under jquery link...It generates alerts and works fine !!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rowCount = $('.table-condensed .table-warehouse tr').length;

    if( rowCount == 0){
        alert("no rows in tbody");
    }else{
        alert("tbody has rows");
    }
</script>
```